# When and when not to use 'return' keyword in a funciton?

Tags: javascript

I have learned in "Function section" of the Javascript course in Codecademy that: to call a function, we have to use 'return' keyword inside the function. But in the "Array section" of the Javascript course found a function can be called without using 'return' keyword inside that function. Can anyone explain when I must use 'return' keyword inside the function and when it is optional?
I am attaching the code snippet for Your reference.

```
const flowers = ['peony', 'daffodil', 'marigold'];

function addFlower(arr) {
  arr.push('lily');
}

addFlower(flowers);
```

Comment: Well, here's the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) of `return`

Comment: I guess the answer is, it depends. In your example the `.push` function will alter the array given (`flowers`) and itself returns the new length of the array. So if you want to know the length you can use `return`. Functions inside functions are executed no matter if there is a `return` or not.

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary that function must return any value.

When you not required anything from the function then you don't require to return anything. This function called void function.

If you require some value from function the you must return it.

Answer (score 2):

The return keyword is used only to get back some value from the function to the caller so that the value can be used later. In case, if you don't want to use any value from the function, you can omit the return statement.

In the case of objects as a parameter, if that object itself is changed, then it will change the original copy which was passed as well. So, at that time also, no need to return that object from the function.

Answer (score 2):

With the return statement you actually return a value to the caller. For example:

```js
function add(a, b) {
  return a+b;
}

var c = add(5,7);
```

If you have a function that just performs a task without a return value you do not use the keyword. E.g.:

```js
function sayHello() {
  console.log('Hello');
}

sayHello();
```

Note: A return statement ends the function; statements after the return will not be executed.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, there might be a need for returning a value, just like `Array.prototype.push()` is doing it. Please see the documentation of [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

```js
function addOneFlower(flowers) {
  const newFlower = "Bellflowers";
  
  return flowers.push(newFlower);
}

const flowerArr = [];
let sizeOfFlowerArr = addOneFlower(flowerArr);
// sizeOfFlowerArr starts with 1

sizeOfFlowerArr = addOneFlower(flowerArr);
// sizeOfFlowerArr increased to 2
```

Comment: This is actually the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use `return` when you might want to transfer information from inside the function directly to the caller. For example, maybe a caller of `addFlower` would want to know the name of the flower that was added. Then you would probably have something like

```
const addedFlower = addFlower(flowers);
```

This assigns the return value of `addFlower` to the `addedFlower` variable. But for that to work, `addFlower` should `return` something, eg:

```
function addFlower(arr) {
  arr.push('lily');
  return 'lily';
}
```

If you don't ever need to transfer information *directly* from inside the function to the caller, then all invocations of the function should be in a standalone line, like

```
addFlower(flowers);
```

and there's no need (or sense) for `addFlower` to `return` anything.

Note that the caller may *sometimes* want information that the function returns, but sometimes a caller may not care about it. But the function may not know which, so it should `return` regardless, and the caller of the function can use the resulting expression if it wants, or the caller can ignore it. Eg, in the same script, there might be one line like

```
const addedFlower = addFlower(flowers);
```

and another like

```
addFlower(flowers); // Don't care about the return value
```

In this case, `addFlower` should be returning something regardless, leaving it completely up the caller to do something with the result.

Answer (score 1):

The function when called will run till it reaches a return statement, or the end. If you are using a function with return value, you need to have a return statement in your function definition.

But if you are using a function with no return statement and it can run till the end of the function, than you don't have to have a return statement in the function definition. For example:

```
function helloWorld() {
  console.log('Hello World');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the simple example I can give you is this.
let say you have some unknown numbers you want to calculate when the user gives you an input.
for example, you ask your users when he/she was born to calculate his/her age.

```
function calcAge(yearBorn){
   var age = 2019 - yearBorn;
   return 'hello user your age is ' + age;
}
calcAge(1993);
```

when the user gives you the year she/he was born, it will be passed to the yearBorn parameter and will be calculated against the current year. but to use it, you should return it. if you don't return it you will get 'undefined', when you call the function. You have probably seen the console.log() function previously. it is used only on the dev tool in the browser for development purposes. if you want to use the end result from that function, you should use the return keyword then you will get the calculated age instead of 'undefined'! this has something to do with function scope. if you declare the age variable outside of the function and reassign it again in the function, you can probably use the age without the return statement like below.

```
 var age2;
 function calcAge2(yearBorn){
    age2 = 2019 - yearBorn;
 }
```

When you call it, since the age2 is declared outside of the function, you will be able to access it from the global scope. even if you didn't return it, the function call will update the age2 variable based on the calculation. but declaring a variable in the global scope is not a good practice.

Comment: Thanks for Your wonderful support and I completely agree with You. Can You explain why 'return' keyword is not used in the following code and still function could be called?

    const flowers = ['peony', 'daffodil', 'marigold'];

    function addFlower(arr) {
      arr.push('lily');
    }

    addFlower(flowers);

Comment: in your example, you already declared the variable outside of the function scope

Answer (score 0):

in your example, you have already declared the variable outside of your function.
with const flowers = ['peony', 'daffodil', 'marigold'], you are only pushing additional items in your array by calling the function. if you had declared your flowers array inside the function like bellow, though it is not the best example

```
function addFlower() {
    const flowers = ['peony', 'daffodil', 'marigold'];
    flowers.push('lily');
    return flowers;
}
```

then you have to use the return statement to return the value of the array to use it later. 
in your case, you are just adding the items in your pre-existing array that was declared in the outer scope.
you don't have to use return if your intention is not to return the value from the function local scope.
since you declared your variable outside of the function, you can update those values without a return statement like you did. but if you want to return a value from a function to be used, you should use the return statement.
check the two examples below. copy them and play around with them in the console.

**On the first one since I declared the variable sum inside the function (in the local scop), I have to use the return statement to get the value that is calculated when I call the function. otherwise, the function call will give me undefined value;**

```
function add(x, y){
   let sum = x + y;
   return sum;
}
```

**but on the second one, the sum variable is declared outside of the function in the global scope. all I am doing when I call the function is updating the pre-existing variable sum. because of that, I don't need to use the return statement here**

```
 let sum;
    function add(x, y){
      sum = x + y;
    }
```

My advice to you, the more you learn about javascript, the dot will connect for you. just keep learning. I have been there. sometimes it feels like nothing makes sense. trust me the dots will connect as you learn more.